# How to handle extra value in Java Streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have the following 2 objects

```
Product       ProductInventory
-type         -Product
-price        -quantity  
              -country
```

I need to find cheapest by iterating through a list of `ProductInventory`. The steps are;

1. if `product.type == input_type` and `quantity > input_quantity`
2. `totalPrice = product.price * input_quantity`
3. if `country != input_country` then `totalPrice = totalPrice + input_tax`
4. sort records by the `totalPrice` from min to max
5. get first record & map to a new object (country, quantity remaining, total price)

I cannot work out how to handle step 2, where I need to generate a total price, but how to create & use this field in a stream?

Comment: You have `totalPrice` value, which cannot be stored in anywhere, why not add that value to `ProductInventory`?

Comment: did you use a wrapper class? Or inserted into inventory class directly?

Comment: I am trying to insert it in wrapper class because as you know productInventory has a different purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `totalPrice` field declared in `ProductInventory`, you can do the following;

```
private Optional<FinalEntity> doLogic(String inputCountry, String inputType, Integer inputQuantity, Integer inputTax) {
    return Stream.of(new Inventory(new Product("cola", 15), "germany", 1000))
            .filter(inv -> inv.getProduct().getType().equals(inputType) && inv.getQuantity() > inputQuantity)
            .peek(inv -> {
                Integer tax = inv.getCountry().equals(inputCountry) ? 0 : inputTax;
                inv.setTotalPrice((inv.getProduct().getPrice() * inputQuantity) + tax);
            })
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Inventory::getTotalPrice))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Util::mapToFinalEntity);
}
```

where

```
public class Product {

    String type;
    Integer price;

    // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

and

```
public class Inventory {

    Product product;
    String country;
    Integer quantity;
    Integer totalPrice;

    // getters, setters, and constructors
}
```

the result value is either an `Optional.empty()`, or you will have your resulting value in final entity format, I skipped last `map to new object (country, quantity remaining, total price)` which is a simple step at that point.

If you do not wish to have this field in `Inventory`, you can create a wrapper class on top of it, containing `totalPrice`, and map to it from inventories at the beginning of the stream.

Comment: Why not use `map` rather than a contrived `peek`?

Comment: @apophis it is possible to use a map, thought there might be duplicate keys, you have to consider such cases. The question was asking to have a single stream with a lambda solution to the totalPrice value, my answer is exactly that.

Comment: @apophis using `peek` is **required** if the objects in the `Stream` are mutated. Using a `map` in this case breaks the contract of the method and results in UB.